# error: package androidx.core.content does not exist

Tags: angular, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I developp an Ionic App, and I need to open an email interface from my App. I use Cordova Email Plugin: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.

when I try to run my App on android studio I get this error:

```
error: package androidx.core.content does not exist
 
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
```

These are some infos about my App:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.17.1 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.18
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.18
   @angular/cli                  : 11.2.18
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 2.4.7
   @capacitor/android : 2.5.0
   @capacitor/core    : 2.4.7
   @capacitor/ios     : 2.5.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.4.1

System:

   NodeJS : v14.17.6 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.15
   OS     : Windows 10
```

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by modifying the dependencies section in <YOUR_PROJECT_HOME>\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\build.gradle file , added the "androidx.core:core:1.3.2" package to dependencies

**existing**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.apache.cordova:framework:$cordovaAndroidVersion"
}
```

**change**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.apache.cordova:framework:$cordovaAndroidVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.2'
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,I applied this solution and my app build successefuly but when I try to open email interface from my app I catch the same error as this issue : [https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/issues/361] wich is about Android 11, even if I upgreded the version of the plugin to the last one . any ideas to resolve the problem?